# I need corresponding values to appear automatically in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have 2 Google Sheets. Now in excel 1 The name column in sheet 1 is A and the address column in Sheet 1 is B. Now I have another sheet which already has these data, name and addresses etc. Now, what I want to do is when I write the name(A) in sheet 1, I want the column B(address) in the same sheet to automatically lookup the sheet 2 for the corresponding address to name (A) and show the address in that cell.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need: **`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A); VLOOKUP(A2:A; 'Tab B'!A2:B; 2; 0); ))`**

which means that **`IF`** ID from **`Tab B`** is found in **`Tab A`**, formula will return **`2`** (second) column from range **`A:B`** of **`Tab B`** in sorted order based on IDs in **A** column of **`Tab A`** - hence that **`0`**

here is demo spreadsheet: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MUesMmT8JVTb_tqfaxfn38EWmDs_emByD8tBvZA_TKk/edit#gid=0)**

[image]